# Javascript - Android onscreen Keyboard changes background size

Tags: javascript, android, html, css, angular

I am currently trying to develop an Angular app with bootstrap and have some issues with the background. When the keyboard opens, the background resizes. When changing to the password field the number row of the keyboard appears and triggers another resize.It looks like the picture is "jumping" Is there any way to prevent the background from resizing?

Here is the code of the form:

```
 <div class="col-sm-6 mx-auto my-auto">
  <div class="card card-block">
    <div class=""><h1 class="text-center">Anmelden</h1></div>

    <form #f="ngForm" role="form" (ngSubmit)="login(f)">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="username">Username</label>
        <input type="email"
               #name="ngModel"
               name="username"
               class="form-control input small"
               id="username"
               required
               placeholder="Username" email>
      </div>
      <div *ngIf="((!name.valid || name.pristine) && isSubmitted == true)" class="alert alert-danger">Email ist nicht gültig</div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="password">Password</label>
        <input type="password" ngModel name="password" required #password class="form-control" id="password" placeholder="Password">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group" >
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
        <a [routerLink]="['/register']">Noch kein Konto? Hier klicken zum registrieren!<br></a>
      </div>
      <div [ngBusy]="{busy: busy, message: 'Bitte warten...'}"></div>
      <div *ngIf="!success" class="alert alert-danger">Passwort und/oder E-Mail falsch!</div>
      <p>{{ f.valid ? 'VALID':'Invalid' }}</p>


    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

```css
html, body {


  height: 100%;

}

body {
  background: url(assets/road-clouds-street-path.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  height:100%;
  overflow-x:hidden;

}
```

What I already tried was to set the body height in this onResize function

```
  function onResize() {
  console.log(window.outerHeight);
  var m = document.getElementById("taxi"), c = m.style;
  c.height = window.outerHeight;
```

}

But it seems linke window.outerheight also changes and therefore has no effect.

JsFiddle example:

https://jsfiddle.net/2a0t6816/